# Why does extra log() influence the threadpool used for calculating fromCallable()?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm playing with Project Reactor and facing unintuitive behaviour.

Take the following example:

```
    Mono.fromCallable(() -> calculate())
    //.log()
      .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
      .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("thread: " +   Thread.currentThread().getName()))
      .block();
```

When I uncomment `log()`, `calculate()` runs on `main` thread but when I leave it in, the method is executed on `boundedElastic`. Why is that `log()` changes the behaviour of the Mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I annotated the code snippet a bit to explain what's going on.

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> calculate()) // <1>
  //.log() // <2>
  .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // <3>
  .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println( // <4>
    "thread: " +   Thread.currentThread().getName()))
  .block();
```

What you experience is called operator fusion, which you can read more on [David Karnok's blog](https://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2016/03/operator-fusion-part-1.html). When <2> is present, it doesn't allow fusion between <3> and <1>. When you comment it out, <3> fuses with <1> and the `MonoCallable`'s argument can be called on the `Scheduler` that delivers values to operator/`Subscriber` following the `publishOn` operator.

<1> the source is Callable, which allows some operators to take advantage of its property of being finite.

<2> the `log` operator is not Callable so any operator following it won't be able to apply this optimization.

<3> when this operator is assembled, it notices the current state of the chain and is able to apply some optimizations, such as delaying the call to `Callable.call()` to the point that the onNext signal is delivered downstream.

<4> the print statement is always executed on a `Thread` from the `Scheduler` specified in <3>.

Now on to the actual problem here. The typical situation when users of Reactor run into asking this question is that the `Callable` needs to be executed on a specific `Scheduler`, especially if it is of a blocking nature. We recently [improved the documentation for this scenario](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking). Essentially, what you are looking for is the `subscribeOn()` operator. The `publishOn` operator guarantees the values are delivered on a specific Scheduler, but don't specify where the value extraction happens. Therefore, this particular optimization leads to such surprises when it can no longer be applied.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the implementation of `publishOn` method, you will notice that it has a specific case for when it is called immediately after `Callable`. In this case, it returns `MonoSubscribeOnCallable` and the callable is executed on the scheduler that is passed to `publishOn`. This is why you see such a behaviour.

However, if you add a `.log` operator between your `fromCallable` and `publishOn`, then this special case is not applied. This is because `this` pointer now refers to `MonoLogFuseable`, and as a result, `MonoPublishOn` is returned with default behavior.

```java
public final Mono<T> publishOn(Scheduler scheduler) {
    if(this instanceof Callable) {
        if (this instanceof Fuseable.ScalarCallable) {
            try {
                T value = block();
                return onAssembly(new MonoSubscribeOnValue<>(value, scheduler));
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                //leave MonoSubscribeOnCallable defer error
            }
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Callable<T> c = (Callable<T>)this;
        return onAssembly(new MonoSubscribeOnCallable<>(c, scheduler));
    }
    return onAssembly(new MonoPublishOn<>(this, scheduler));
}
```

Here is the commit where this change was introduced: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/commit/41d9dae7256ffc36a07db7a9f5fa4d95182a5ad9

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any ticket reference or explanation to clearly understand why it works the way it does.